# Easy way to get all tables out to S3 on a nightly basis?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to be able to dump the contents of each table in my redshift data warehouse each night to S3.

The outcome that I want to achieve is the same outcome as if I was manually issueing an UNLOAD command for each table.

For something this simple, I assumed I could use something like data pipeline or glue, but these don’t seem to make this easy.

Am I looking at this problem wrong?  This seems like it should be simple.

Comment: You have different approaches. One is Datapipeline, you can create one that runs a sql script (unload blabla). You can make a script in ruby/python/whatever that execute the sql and run it by crontab or lambda and cloudwatch to run the sql but probably the datapipeline is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had this process but in reverse recently.  My solution: a python script that queried pg_schema (to grab eligible table names), and then looped through the results using the table name as a parameter in an `INSERT` query.  I ran the script as a cron job in an EC2.

In theory, you could set up the script via Lambda or as a ShellCommand in Pipeline.  But I could never get that to work, whereas a cron job was super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific use case for explicitly `UNLOAD`ing data to S3? Like being able to use that data with Spark/Hive?

If not, you should be scheduling Snapshots of Redshift cluster to S3 every day. This happens by default anyway.
Snapshots are stored in S3 as well.
Snapshots are incremental and fast. You can restore entire clusters using snapshots.

You can also restore individual tables from snapshots.

Here is the documentation about it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as creating a script (shell/python/...) and putting that in crontab. Somewhere in the lines of (snippet from a shell script):

```
psql -U$username -p $port -h $hostname $database -f path/to/your/unload_file.psql
```

and your `unload_file.psql` would contain the standard Redshift unload statement:

```
unload ('select * from schema.tablename') to 's3://scratchpad_bucket/filename.extension'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXX' 
[options];
```

Put your shell script in a crontab and execute it daily at the time when you want to take the backup.

> However, remember:
>
> 1. While taking backups is indispensible, daily full backups will generate a mammoth bill for s3. You **should** rotate the backups /
>      log files i.e. regularly delete them or take a backup from s3 and
>      store locally.
> 2. A *full daily backup* might not be the best thing to do. Check whether you can do it incrementally.
> 3. It would be better that you tar and gzip files and then send them to s3 rather than storing an Excel or a csv.